# Can I write a constructor for a Scheme (Racket) struct that takes a variable number of arguments?

Tags: struct, constructor, scheme, racket, variadic-functions

I understand how to write a function that takes an arbitrary number of arguments using the dot notation. Example: `(define (func-name . args) func-body)`.

And I understand how to use a constructor guard to preprocess the constructors arguments, allowing me to pass different types to the constructor. Example:

```
(struct struct-id (field-ids)
    #:guard (lambda (field-ids type-name) process-fields))
```

But that's as close as I can get. Can you write a guard that takes an arbitrary number of arguments? Or is there some other way to modify what a struct constructor does?

Answer (score 3):

Just write a wrapper:

```
(struct struct-id (a b c d) #:constructor-name struct-id*
      #:guard (lambda (a b c d type-name) do-stuff))

(define (struct-id (a) (b) (c) (d 'default-value))
        (struct-id* a b c d))
```

That gives you a constructor in which all the field arguments are optional. Defining them this way instead of with dot notation saves you from having to parse through the rest-argument.

I supplied a default value for `d`, and Racket will make the default value of the others `#f`.

You can also define it to have keyword arguments:

```
(define (struct-id #:a (a #f) #:b (b #f) #:c c #:d (d 'default))
        (struct-id* a b c d))
```

In the above case, `#:c` is a required argument because I left off the parentheses, I provided `'default` as the default value of `d`, and the others will have a default value of `#f`, which this time has to be explicitly provided. Keywords can be passed to the constructor in any order.

If you're using a lot of structs, you might want a macro to define the wrapper for you:

```
(begin-for-syntax
 (require (planet jphelps/loop)) ;; Installs a library on first use. Be patient.
 (define stx-symbol->string (compose symbol->string syntax->datum))
 (define (make-constructor-name stx-name)
    (datum->syntax stx-name
      (string->symbol
       (string-append (stx-symbol->string stx-name) "*"))))
 (define (stx-symbol->stx-keyword stx-symbol)
   (datum->syntax stx-symbol
    (string->keyword
     (symbol->string
      (syntax->datum stx-symbol))))))

(define-syntax struct*
  (lambda (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
        ((_ struct-name fields . options)
         #`(begin
             (struct struct-name fields . options)
             (define (#,(make-constructor-name #'struct-name) 
                . #,(loop for name in (syntax-e #'fields)
                        collect (stx-symbol->stx-keyword name)
                        collect #`(#,name #f)))
               (struct-name . fields)))))))
```

Then define your structs like this:

```
(struct* struct-id (a b c d) #:guard whatever)
```

You'll automatically get a keyword-based constructor named `struct-id*` that doesn't conflict with names that are generated by the `struct` form.

### EDIT

Apparently the above macro as it was originally written didn't work in module-based programs. I only tested it at the REPL, which behaves more like a Lisp in that you're allowed to redefine things. This masked the fact that `struct`'s `#:constructor-name` option adds and *additional* constructor name instead of overriding the existing constructor name. This is in spite of the fact that there's an `#:extra-constructor-name` option that also creates an additional constructor name.

Fixing this problem in a way that would be completely seamless would require you to reimplement the entire `struct` macro. You'd have to rename the struct and then generate not only the constructor, but all of the accessors and mutators. An easier workaround would be to generate a constructor with a different name from the original constructor. I have edited the code above to implement this workaround.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you could specify a specific constructor with `#:constructor-name`. That's very helpful.

Comment: I had a few problems using this macro? I can't squeeze it into a comment so I made another answer.

Comment: The simple wrapper example you gave doesn't seem to work. As Greg points out below, you can't redefine the function `struct-id`.

Comment: On a different note, in this case, I do want to use the dot notation because the examples I'm thinking of aren't just taking a few optional arguments, but arbitrarily many, which will be bundled up into a list. I'd just like to be able to call the constructor without having to use list notation on them (e.g., `(queue item1 item2 ...)` rather than `(queue (list item1 item2 ...))`.

Comment: I fixed the duplicate-definition problem.

Comment: You'll need to have some form of keyword arguments if there are arbitrarily many optional arguments and a random selection of them will be used. Although the next problem you'll run into is that Racket's `apply` function is completely broken when it comes to keywords.

Answer (score 3):

Although you can specify another name for the constructor with `#:constructor-name`, in my experience that doesn't "free up" the struct identifier to be used as a function name:

```
(struct baz (a b c) #:transparent #:constructor-name -baz)
(-baz 1 2 3) ;(baz 1 2 3)
(define (baz a b c)
  (-baz 1 2 3))
; module: duplicate definition for identifier
;   at: baz
;   in: (define-values (baz) (new-lambda (a b c) (-baz 1 2 3)))
```

So I usually just define an *alternative* constructor using another name, and use that instead of the default one (which is still available to use, if desired).

---

As for a macro to do this, plus supply keyword args and optional args: I wasn't able to get the macro in the other answer to work for me.

- The first problem is the one I mention above.
- It isn't `append*`-ing (flattening) the `(#:kw id)` arg specs in the function definition.
- It hardwires the identifier `construct` instead of one formed from the user's struct identifier.
- Finally I prefer not to use a CL `loop` macro, pulled in from an old-style PLaneT package.

Instead, what does work for me is modifying and extending the code I showed in [a blog post](http://www.greghendershott.com/2013/03/keyword-structs.html), as follows:

```
#lang racket/base

(require (for-syntax racket/base
                     racket/list
                     racket/syntax
                     syntax/parse))

(begin-for-syntax
 (define syntax->keyword (compose1 string->keyword symbol->string syntax->datum)))

(define-syntax (struct/kw stx)
  (define-syntax-class field
    (pattern id:id
             #:with ctor-arg #`(#,(syntax->keyword #'id) id))
    (pattern [id:id default:expr]
             #:with ctor-arg #`(#,(syntax->keyword #'id) [id default])))
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_ struct-id:id (field:field ...) opt ...)
     (with-syntax ([ctor-id (format-id #'struct-id "~a/kw" #'struct-id)]
                   [((ctor-arg ...) ...) #'(field.ctor-arg ...)]) ;i.e. append*
       #'(begin
           (struct struct-id (field.id ...) opt ...)
           (define (ctor-id ctor-arg ... ...) ;i.e. append*
             (struct-id field.id ...))))]))
```

Example usage:

```
;; Define a struct type
(struct/kw foo (a b [c #f]) #:transparent)

;; Use normal ctor
(foo 1 2 3)                ; => (foo 1 2 3)

;; Use keyword ctor
(foo/kw #:a 1 #:b 2 #:c 3) ; => (foo 1 2 3)

;; Use keyword ctor, taking advantage of default arg for #:c field
(foo/kw #:a 1 #:b 2)       ; => (foo 1 2 #f)
```

Granted this is simplistic, it would need more work to support everything normal `struct` can do.

Comment: I'll probably just end up using the alternative constructor name as you suggest. It's what I was going to do anyway, but I was hoping that it was possible to make the original constructor work with arbitrarily many arguments.

Comment: I see. I never tried using this code from a module. It works fine at the REPL, where you're allowed to redefine things.

Comment: The loop generates `(kw (id default))` not `(kw id)`, and it is flattened by the use of two `collect` clauses in the loop macro, one for the keyword, and the other for the `(id default-value)` pair.

Comment: Also, in my opinion Racket's new `pkgs` system is markedly inferior to the old PLaneT system. That is why I am still using PLaneT.

Comment: @ErikWennstrom Although I haven't tried it, you could probably use `(provide (rename-out [original alternative]))` to get that effect outside the module, at least.